# How to access the vector assets in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

The 1.4 update of android studio introduced a bunch of vector icons that follow the principle of material design.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/09/android-studio-14.html
Where can I access these images from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the project, inside the **Project panel**.
Select **New** and then choose **Vector Asset** option.
Maybe a popup will advert you that you need to have a new Gradle version in order to use this function. That's ok and you can fix this issue by replacing one line into your Gradle file, inside the tag `dependencies`.

Replace the line 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`
 with this 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3'`

Note that there are two Gradle files associated to your app. One of them will content a line similar to that one I exposed above.

Build your project and repeat the first steps and everything should work fine. In the worst case restart the Android Studio IDE.

Answer (score 1):

right click on res folder and go to new ->Vector Asset

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Project>app>res>drawable>Right Click on drawable>new>Vector Asset
```

By following the above steps you will get Vector Asset